# How can i calculate the percentages and update the progressBar in the splash screen form?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

I made a splash screen form:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.IO;
using System.Threading;

namespace GetHardwareInfo
{
    public partial class SplashScreen : Form
    {
        public SplashScreen()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private Mutex mutex = new Mutex();
        public void SyncedClose()
        {
            mutex.WaitOne();
            this.Close();
            mutex.ReleaseMutex();
        }
        public void UpdateProgressBar(int percentage)
        {

            if (this.InvokeRequired)
            {
                mutex.WaitOne();
                if (!IsDisposed)
                    this.BeginInvoke(new Action<int>(UpdateProgresPRV), percentage);
                mutex.ReleaseMutex();
            }
            else
            {
                UpdateProgresPRV(percentage);
            }
        }

        private void UpdateProgresPRV(int per)
        {
            if (progressBar1.IsDisposed) return;
            progressBar1.Value = per;
        }

        private void SplashScreen_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }
    }
}
```

The SplashScreen form have in the designer a background image and on the image a progressBar1.

Then in form1 i did in the top:

```
List<string> WmiClassesKeys = new List<string>();
IEnumerable<Control> controls;
string comboBoxesNames;
SplashScreen splash = new SplashScreen();
```

Then in the constructor:

```
controls = LoopOverControls.GetAll(this, typeof(ComboBox));
            string[] lines = File.ReadAllLines(@"c:\wmiclasses\wmiclasses1.txt");

                foreach (string line in lines)
                {
                    foreach (ComboBox comboBox in controls.OfType<ComboBox>())
                    {
                        if (line.StartsWith("ComboBox"))
                        {

                            comboBoxesNames = line.Substring(14);
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            if (line.StartsWith("Classes"))
                            {

                                if (comboBox.Name == comboBoxesNames)
                                {
                                    comboBox.Items.Add(line.Substring(14));

                                }

                            }
                        }
                    }
                }

                foreach (ComboBox comboBox in controls.OfType<ComboBox>())
                {
                    comboBox.SelectedIndex = 0;
                }
```

The method GetAll is to loop over specific controls:

```
public static IEnumerable<Control> GetAll(Control control, Type type)
        {
            var controls = control.Controls.Cast<Control>();

            return controls.SelectMany(ctrl => GetAll(ctrl, type))
                                      .Concat(controls)
                                      .Where(c => c.GetType() == type);
        }
```

When i'm running the program it's taking some time to make the foreach loops in this time i need to show the SplashScreen and update the progressBar untill the foreach loops over.

This is how it look like now:

[image: SplashScreen]

Comment: You are posting way too much information - to be frank I doubt many will bother to read through all this information. One thing I notice is you have a Thread.Sleep() call. That should never be used on the UI thread of a WinForms program. Instead you should rewrite that part of your program to use a WinForms Timer (not a Thread Timer), and do what needs to be done in the Timer's Tick event handler.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can count how many controls you need to load and put in `Maximum` Property. (Of course, if it's not a fixed value, you can change it codebehind using for example `progressBar.Maximum = x;`)

Then to keep refreshing it, use `progressBar.PerformStep()` (it'll add values according to `Step` Property) or just simply use the old `progressBar.Value++`

On your case I guess it would be like this inside the Constructor:

```
ProgressBar progressBar =  splash.Controls["myProgressBar"];

foreach (string line in lines)
                    {
                        foreach (ComboBox comboBox in controls.OfType<ComboBox>())
                        {
                            if (line.StartsWith("ComboBox"))
                            {

                                comboBoxesNames = line.Substring(14);
                            }
                            else
                            {
                                if (line.StartsWith("Classes"))
                                {

                                    if (comboBox.Name == comboBoxesNames)
                                    {
                                        comboBox.Items.Add(line.Substring(14));

                                    }
                                }
                            }
                            progressBar.PerformStep();
                        }
                    }
```

As you told it takes some time in FOREACH loop, I suppose it's there where you want to add the 'progress', if not, you'll need to refresh it everytime a Combo is invoked, that's the only difference.